# Calling jQuery function by var reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to change the jQuery function called using the value of the switch. In this particular case It will grab the selector then use whatever the value of 'direction to call on jQuery function.

```
$('#'+the_name).value_of_switch(options.speed_up);
```

How can I accomplish this?

```
switch(direction){
    case 'up':   direction = 'slideDown';
    break;

    case 'down':  direction = 'slideUp';
    break;
}

$('#'+the_name).slideDown(options.speed_up);
```

Comment: _Have tried a couple ways without success._ What have you tried?

Comment: `$('#'+the_name)[direction=='up'?'slideUp':'slideDown'](options.speed_up);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too sure this is what you mean, does that help?

```
$('#'+the_name)["YOUR STRING VALUE HERE"](options.speed_up);
```

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var direction = 'up'; 
var theName = $('#the_name');
  var options = {speed_up:'slow'};
switch(direction){
      case 'up':  
            direction = 'slideUp' ;
      break;

      case 'down': 
            direction = 'slideUp' ;
      break;
}

theName[direction](options.speed_up);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/VrPxd/32/